# How to trunc a date to seconds in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[This page](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php]) mentions how to trunc a timestamp to minutes/hours/etc. in Oracle.

How would you trunc a timestamp to seconds in the same manner?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since the precision of `DATE` is to the second (and no fractions of seconds), there is no need to `TRUNC` at all.

The data type `TIMESTAMP` allows for fractions of seconds.  If you convert it to a `DATE` the fractional seconds will be removed - e.g.

```
select cast(systimestamp as date) 
  from dual;
```

Comment: I dont understand why this has so many up votes and was chosen as the answer.  It doesnt work, at least not in 12c.  Original post was in 2008 - maybe it worked then.  Today in 12c it returns full date with time including seconds.  ```select cast(systimestamp as date) from dual;``` returns ```12/27/2019 7:54:35 AM```

Comment: Yes, as it should.  But not *fractions* of seconds e.g. `12/27/2019 7:54:35.534648`.

Comment: Ah I see.  I misinterpreted the question as how can OP truncate seconds off of a date.   Such that it would return ```12/27/2019 7:54```

Comment: I would, but the answer needs to be edited in order to do so.

Comment: @alexherm OK fair enough.  But I won't be editing it because in 11 years there has only been one person who hasn't understood that "fractional seconds will be removed" doesn't mean "whole seconds will be removed" :-)

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry, but all my predecessors seem to be wrong.

```
select cast(systimestamp as date) from dual
```

..does not truncate, but rounds to the next second instead.

I use a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TRUNC_TS(TS IN TIMESTAMP) RETURN DATE AS
BEGIN

    RETURN TS;

END;
```

For example:

```
SELECT systimestamp
    ,trunc_ts(systimestamp) date_trunc
    ,CAST(systimestamp AS DATE) date_cast 
FROM dual;
```

Returns:

```
    SYSTIMESTAMP                       DATE_TRUNC             DATE_CAST
    21.01.10 15:03:34,567350 +01:00    21.01.2010 15:03:34    21.01.2010 15:03:35
```

Comment: I ran your code, but can't reproduce your findings.  In a few dozen tests (most of which would have been affected by rounding), the seconds portion never differed between the three results.  What version of Oracle are you on?  (I was on 11.2).

Comment: CAST will round prior to version 11i and truncate after.
See [Implicit Data Conversion ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i163326) in the Oracle HTML documentation.

Answer (score 2):

On the general topic of truncating Oracle dates, here's the documentation link for the format models that can be used in date trunc() AND round() functions

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions242.htm#sthref2718

"Seconds" is not listed because the granularity of the DATE datatype is seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I used function like this:

```
FUNCTION trunc_sec(p_ts IN timestamp)
IS
    p_res timestamp;
BEGIN
    RETURN TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(p_ts, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI');
END trunc_sec;
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go, since, unlike most of these answers, it is independent of the version of Oracle. It's not quite correct, though - you've missed out the seconds. Should be something like:

to_date(to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

Answer (score 2):

trunc work to min only, cast to date `to_char(START_TIME,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')`

or simply `select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') from dual;`

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php

Answer (score 1):

To truncate a `timestamp` to seconds you can cast it to a date:

```sql
CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
```

To then perform the `TRUNC`'s in the article:

```sql
TRUNC(CAST(timestamp AS DATE), 'YEAR')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something on the order of:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'SS') from dual;
```

Comment: While this is the most obvious solution, `SS` is not a valid format for to_char, and fails with `ORA-01899: bad precision specifier`. Its also not listed as a viable option on: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084

Comment: Interesting.  It runs fine in my instance.   I'm running 12c (12.2.0.1.0) 64 bit.  Your link goes to Trunc/Round.  The example uses to_char.  try https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

Comment: Hmm, then it must have been fixed in a more recent version... I'll try to pinpoint it to a specific version.